# Why is C/C++ preprocessor adding a space here?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a tiny problem with a preprocessor that puzzles me and I cannot find any explanation to it in the documentation/preprocessor/language spec.

```
#define booboo() aaa
booboo()bbb
booboo().bbb
```

is preprocessed into:

```
aaa bbb   <--- why is space added here
aaa.bbb
```

After handling trigraphs, continued lines and comments, preprocessor works on preprocessor directives and divides input into preprocessing tokens and whitespace. booboo's replacement list comprises one pp-token which is identifier 'aaa'. booboo()bbb is divided into pp-tokens: 'booboo', '(', ')', 'bbb'. Sequence of 'booboo', '(', ')' is recognised as functional macro invocation and it should be expanded to 'aaa' and imho in output should look like 'aaabbb'. I said look like since - to human - it would look like one token whereas compiler would get 2 tokens 'aaa' and 'bbb' since no '##' operator was used that allows pp-token concatenation. Why/what rule makes cpp (c preprocessor) place additional space between 'aaa' and 'bbb' when 'booboo().bbb' results in 'aaa.bbb' without space?

Is this because cpp tries to make output (which is for humans mostly) unambinuous? Human is not able to tell that 'aaabbb' is composed from 2 tokens as it sees token's spelling only. Am I right? I've read C99 documentation about preprocessor and gcc's documentation for cpp. I see nothing about it.

If I am right we have similar situation here:

```
#define baba() +
baba()+
baba()-
```

results in:

```
+ +
+-
```

Otherwise (if '++' is the output) it would look to a human like '++' token but there would be 2 tokens '+' and '+'. Is it like with '##' operator that cpp checks if concatenation produces valid token but in shown cases wants to prevent human that concatenation was performed? '+-' is not ambiguous hence no space added

Comment: It's worth noting: the C standard says nothing about tools that stop halfway through the compilation process.

Comment: Related (possible dup): [cpp expansion of macro with no token-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813619/cpp-expansion-of-macro-with-no-token-string/30813841#30813841)

Comment: Note that very often spacing does not matter in C or C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of preprocessing is to transform the source file into a list of tokens. In your case the list of tokens would look like, after tokenization:

```
....
booboo()
bbb
....
```

and then after macro replacement:

```
....
aaa
bbb
....
```

Then the compiler translates the list of tokens into an executable.

The whitespace you are seeing is just an implementation detail that your compiler etc. has chosen to lay out the preprocessing tokens when displaying an intermediate result to you.   The standards say nothing about any intermediate processing files. It is not required that there be a separate program to do preprocessing either.

Comment: @BlueMoon there does not need to be a separate preprocessor at all, so it doesn't have to do anything.   The preprocessing stages of translation are just specified as producing a list of tokens, not producing a file. The "preprocessor output" is an intermediate stage between the source file and the executable.

Comment: @Matt: I would rephrase your answer to sth like (imho better): "The goal of preprocessing is to transform the source file into a list of tokens which then become compiler's input. In your case (after tokenization) the list of tokens would look like this" and would not say 'booboo()' is one token but 3 tokens. The rest is clear and nice.

Comment: @Blue Moon: "there does not need to be a separate preprocessor at all" is sth different than "It's true there doesn't 'need' to be a processor". What Matt says is that compiler does not need to see preprocessor's output the way it should be presented to us (humans). Compiler needs tokens only, no spaces. Preprocessor's feature that allows it to output results of its work is solely for humans so that we could debug ... and have less head scratching ;-)

Comment: @Blue Moon: "why do you even bother looking at 'some preprocessed' output anyway?" - to become wiser than yesterday

Answer (score -2):

I wrote an ANSI C compiler myself in early 90's. As far as I remember, a comment token /*......*/ should be replaced by a single white-space. Macros do text replacement, in place. Not necessary that the tokens which result from text replacement of such macro expansion(s) be legal C language tokens. When a macro is defined as text 'aaa' it is just that text 'aaa' that makes its way into the input stream. C's parser may or may not see valid tokens as a result of that!

Hence, given:

## define booboo() aaa

Expanding booboo()bbb should result in text aaabbb

What does that aaabbb mean is up to the user. But that aaabbb will not be preprocessed even if happens to be the name of a macro. That is for sure. But aaabbb could be a user identifier - no issues there.

Comment: This would concatenate different tokens, which does not happen.

Comment: There is a separate directive `##` for concatenating tokens.