# Why this is not giving compilation error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A -B
#define B -C
#define C 5

int main()
{
  printf("The value of A is %d\n", A); 
  return 0;
}
```

In this, Macros as just get replaced -B becomes --C and finally --5.But This should give compilation error as 5 is a constant right?But it actually prints
"The value of A is 5"
Can anyone explain me clearly when will we get l-value error exactly? Because the following code actually gives l-value required error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT(i, limit) do \
                        { \
                            if (i++ < limit) \
                            { \
                                printf("GeeksQuiz\n"); \
                                continue; \
                            } \
                        }while(1)

int main()
{
    PRINT(0, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Please give me a clear idea when l-value error occurs.I'm tired many times searching an exact reason when will we get l-value error.

Comment: C book needed. The first chapter about arithmetic expressions. And general math adding and subtracting negative numbers. We are not here to teach basics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just need to learn the elementary stuff

Comment: The macro doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't work: `int main() { 0++; return 0; }`

Comment: use **`gcc -E`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is C/C++ preprocessor adding a space here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021711/why-is-c-c-preprocessor-adding-a-space-here)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that negation is actually an arithmetic operator, not something that exists as a property of numbers.

That means `--5` in this case is actually equal to `-(-(5))`. That is, first `5` is negated into `-5`, then that is negated back into `5`.

As for the second macro, then the "arguments" you use in the macro is replaced verbatim with the macro expansion, leading to you attempting to perform the increment operator on a constant integer literal.

---

I'm trying to find a reference to the specification for the behavior of the first macro, but it essentially expands to `- -5`. The inserted space is the reason it's not considered the decrement operator.

Comment: Is it not preDecrement?(--x)...what reason will you tell for the second code where it is post increment (i++) and it gave l-Value required error

Comment: Please read the book. There is explained when you can use ++ operator

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this has to do with how the macros are expanded.  If you run the first piece of code through just the preprocessor, you'll get this:

```
int main()
{
  printf("The value of A is %d\n", - -5);
  return 0;
}
```

Each of the two `-` symbols are separated so you actually get two separate unary `-` operators instead of a predecrement operator `--`.  If you has put `--5` in that place instead you would have gotten an error.